# OpenHandles with Jest and SuperTest if I use express.json()

Tags: node.js, json, express, jestjs, supertest

Using Jest and Supertest for testing my APIs, I receive this warning from Jest:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests.  Consider running Jest with
> `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

After some tests, I have understood that it is due to the Express JSON middleware:

```
export const app: Application = express()
app.use(express.json())
```

I want to avoid using `--forceExit` in my script (`"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --forceExit"`).

Here an example of one of my tests:

```
import request, { Response } from 'supertest'
import { app } from '../../app'
import { endpoints } from '../endpoints'

describe('Registration', () => {
  test('should create a new user', (done) => {
    request(app)
      .post(endpoints.authentication.register)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .send({
        username: 'test',
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'test',
      })
      .expect(200)
      .expect((res: Response) => {
        res.body = {
          status: 200,
          message: 'OK',
          payload: {},
        }
      })
      .end((err) => {
        if (err) return done(err)
        return done()
      })
  })
})
```

Why does this happen? Any suggestions to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: same problem here